# how to multiply floating point values without mul.s in MIPS?

Tags: c, assembly, mips, mips32

I want to do the following operation:

0.1xA^2 #A representing an integer, while 0.1 being a floating point number.

I'm not allowed to use multiplication, division, or shift instructions.

```
.data
num1:       .float 0.1

.text
main:
#A
li $v0, 5
syscall
move $t0, $v0   #A is stored in t0    


li $t3, 0
li $s5, 0

#Finds A^2
Loop1:   
bge $t3, $t0, Quit1
add $s5, $s5, $t0
addi $t3, $t3, 1
j Loop1

Quit1:
li $t3, 0
li $s4, 0

mtc1    $s5,  $f10 #s5 is result of A^2
cvt.s.w $f10, $f10

lwc1    $f18, num1
```

I found A squared above, and I converted A from integer to a Floating point value and stored 0.1 into register $f18.  However, I'm not sure how to multiply 0.1xA without using multiplication or shift instructions.

Comment: It's not multiplication by 0.1, it's division by 10. How many times can you subtract 10 from A^2?

Comment: Oh Okay that makes sense, but I'm confused as to how to do that with floating points, because I'm new to doing conditional statements with floating point numbers

Comment: Does your answer have to be a float or an integer?

Comment: This is basically the same question as [(MIPS) How to perform floating point operations only using addition and subtraction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59119467/mips-how-to-perform-floating-point-operations-only-using-addition-and-subtract).

Comment: The answer has to be in floating point